# how to using a following as files in my flash?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have copied the following code from a forum but I doesn't work in Flash.

On the stage I have 1 jpg that I want to use and I want to use the following code to edit the jpg. So I just edit the  publish >> Class >> LomoBitmapdata
and add a button to call the as files but when I do, the output Flash shows is 'error 1114'.

Here is the file http://www.2shared.com/file/mwNIBwKM/LomoBitmapdata.html

```
package
{
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.GradientType;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.SpreadMethod;
    import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class LomoBitmapdata
    {

        private var bitmapdata:BitmapData;
        private var lightBitmapdata:BitmapData;
        public function LomoBitmapdata()
        {
        }
        public function processLomo(bitmapdata:BitmapData):void{
            this.bitmapdata = bitmapdata;
            processSereen();
            lightBitmapdata = bitmapdata.clone();
            processInvert();
            processRedAdd();
            drawShape();
        }
        private function processPixel(fun:Function):void{
            for(var i:int=0;i<bitmapdata.width;i++){
                for(var j:int=0;j<bitmapdata.height;j++){
                    fun(i,j);
                }
            }
        }
        private function processSereen():void{
            processPixel(sereenBitmaps);
        }
        private function sereenBitmaps(i:int,j:int):void{
            var color32:uint = bitmapdata.getPixel(i,j);
            var red:int = color32 >> 16;
            var green:int = color32 >> 8 & 0xFF;
            var blue:int = color32 & 0xFF;

            var redInt:int = screenBase(red,red);
            var greenInt:int = screenBase(green,green);
            var blueInt:int = screenBase(blue,blue);

            var newUint:uint = redInt << 16 | greenInt << 8 | blueInt;
            bitmapdata.setPixel(i,j,newUint);
        }
        private function screenBase(topPixel:int, bottomPixel:int):int {
            return (255 - ((255 - topPixel) * (255 - bottomPixel))/255);
        }
        private function processInvert():void{
            bitmapdata.colorTransform(new Rectangle(0,0,bitmapdata.width,bitmapdata.height),new ColorTransform(-1,-1,-1,1,255,255,255,1));
        }
        private function processRedAdd():void{
            processPixel(redadd);
        }
        private function redadd(i:int,j:int):void{
            var top:uint = bitmapdata.getPixel(i,j);
            var bottom:uint = lightBitmapdata.getPixel(i,j);

            var red:int = top >> 16;
            var green:int = top >> 8 & 0xFF;
            var blue:int = top & 0xFF;

            var redbottom:int = bottom >> 16;
            var greenbottom:int = bottom >> 8 & 0xFF;
            var bluebottom:int = bottom & 0xFF;

            var resultR:int = redbottom;
            var resultG:int = greenbottom;
            var resultB:int = blue*0.2 + bluebottom*0.8;

            var newUint:uint = resultR << 16 | resultG << 8 | resultB;
            bitmapdata.setPixel(i,j,newUint);
        }
        private function drawShape():void{
            var shape:Shape = new Shape;
            var g:Graphics = shape.graphics;
            var fillType:String = GradientType.RADIAL;
            var colors:Array = [0x000000, 0x000000];
            var alphas:Array = [0, 0.3];
            var ratios:Array = [200,255];
            var matr:Matrix = new Matrix();
            matr.createGradientBox(bitmapdata.width+100, bitmapdata.height+100, 0, 0, 0);
            var spreadMethod:String = SpreadMethod.PAD;
            g.beginGradientFill(fillType, colors, alphas, ratios,matr);  
            g.drawRect(0,0,bitmapdata.width+160,bitmapdata.height+160);
            matr = new Matrix();
            matr.tx = -50;
            matr.ty = -50;
            bitmapdata.draw(shape,matr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please, like tell us what line, what you're trying to do etc? This question is almost worthy of a downvote. You need to explain what you're doing, what happened, what you want to happen etc. You can't just post a huge chunk of code and ask people to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You're not specific enough, so it's difficult to give you specific advice. Your code is a class that contains methods to manipulate a BitmapData object. Typical use would be:

```
//provided you have a BitmapData instance ( let's call it bmd )...
var lomo: LomoBitmapdata = new LomoBitmapdata( );
lomo.processLomo( bmd );
```

If you don't understand this, I would recommend learning about Actionscript 3, otherwise you'll find it impossible to use similar code examples.

Comment: thank you to reply i just start to learn actionscript3 ,before i using as2 just learas3 few week. //provided you have a BitmapData instance ( let's call it bmd )...
var lomo: LomoBitmapdata = new LomoBitmapdata( );  may i know where can i put the follow code to use in a button ? 
lomo.processLomo( bmd );

Comment: [Lost Actionscript Week End](http://tv.adobe.com/show/colin-moocks-lost-actionscript-weekend) is also a great resource